# ReplicationController wait for pods to terminate

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently learning Kubernetes and I'm facing a problem with trying to realize a concept using Kubernetes.

I'm looking for something that works like a `ReplicationController` where I can tell K8s to start 50 replicas. But when I reduce the amount of replicas I need K8s to wait for the pods to terminate by themselves.

I know that there are `Job`s but from what I've read it doesn't seem to be the fitting solution, since jobs are kind of a one-time thing. I need to keep the amount of desired pods until I decrease the amount of desired pods.

Basically a behavior like this:
[image: controllerBehavior]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the kind **Deployment** in background it uses the ReplicationController and ReplicaSets.

ReplicationController is old version while the ReplicaSets is an updated approach to use. In background Kind : Deployment uses.

You can run the number for desired replicas by setting the numbers into the YAML file.

when you scale the deployment it will spin up the number of replicas and at the time of termination, you can again pass the desired replicas.

For example :

```
kubectl scale deployment test-deployment --replicas=50
```

Now running replicas are 50 and you want to scale down

```
kubectl scale deployment test-deployment --replicas=40
```

You can also check out the HPA

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/